# How to pass $this into laravel collection's map()

Tags: php, laravel

How can I access/pass `$this` inside map()? Something like:

```
return $this->map(function ($value) use ($this) {
    return Lang::get($value, [], $this);
});
```

I tried the above but I got an error in my IDE stating: Cannot use `$this` as lexical variable.
This one works but is there a better way to do rather than this:

```
$that = $this;
return $this->map(function ($value) use ($that) {
    return Lang::get($value, [], $that);
});
```

Comment: Doesn't really matter, it's both equivalent

Comment: I just edited my post. curious if there is a way to pass directly $this into map()

Comment: Is collection manage by class?

Answer (score 0):

In `Laravel` closures does not have access to outer scope variables, but it has access to $this context and $this context will always be the class where the closure is called.

```
return $this->map(function ($value) {
    return Lang::get($value, [], $this);
});
```

Therefor this is valid and accepted by coding guidelines. Your problem is instead that the third parameter of `Lang::get()`, is not an `object` but an string there should be an locale, which is defined in the [docs](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Lang.html).

```
return $this->map(function ($value) {
    return Lang::get($value, [], 'en-US');
});
```

So a solution closer to this, is probably what you are looking for, based on you localization settings.